# How to remove Spyder's vertical line on right side of editor pane?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

Spyder has a text wrap feature which includes a gray line at the end of the line. How do you remove it?

[image]

Comment: That is useful. Check pep-8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! 79 characters would be a strange number to use as a default maximum line length otherwise!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Spyder 5.0.0,

You can change the line limit and remove the vertical bar by going to

`Settings` -> `Completion and linting` -> `Code style and formatting` -> `Line length` -> `Show vertical line at that length`

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. However the line still shows at 80 characters once I restart Spyder (4.2.5). Going to settings, the setting is still set to the higher character number, so it no longer reflects the reality in Spyder. Not sure if this was fixed yet in higher versions.

However, completely removing the line seems to persist upon restart.

Comment: I have no problem with this setting on Spyder version 5. I posted this after trying to alter settings in Spyder 4 and causing it to crash. Updating to a newer version should allow the lineless option to persist @doublefelix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a line that assure you comply with programming standard by keeping a maximum line length of about 80 characters. To turn it off go in:

Tools - Preferences - Plugins

Turn on "Completion and linting"
restart Spyder

Tools - Preferences - Completion and linting - Code style and formatting

in Line length uncheck "Show vertical line".